# Navigo JS Router Root Page is reloading

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, routes, client-side

I'm new to Navigo JS Router and also it's my first time creating an application with a client side router. I have defined the routes that I am using, and all does not trigger page reload except whenever I navigate to the home page.

Search.js

```
const Search = {
  render: () => {
    return `
      <section class="section">
        <div class="row topbar">

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
            <h2 class="title text-xs-center">
              <a href="#/">Home Page</a>
            </h2>
          </div>

        </div>
      </section>
    `;
  }
}
```

Detail.js

```
const Detail = {
  render: () => {
    return `
      <section class="section">
        <div class="row topbar">

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
            <h2 class="title text-xs-center">
              <a href="#/">Home Page</a>
            </h2>
          </div>

        </div>


      </section>
    `;
  }
}
```

Searchbar.js

```
const Searchbar = {
  render: async () => {
    return `
      <div class="site-search-container pull-right" id="site-search-container">
        <div class="link-search-all">
          <a href="/#/search">View all</a>
        </div>
      </div>`;
  }
}
```

index.js

```
const render = async (view) => {
  const header = null || document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0];
  const content = null || document.getElementById('content');
  const footer = null || document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0];

  // Render the Header and footer of the page
  header.innerHTML = await Header.render();
  await Header.after_render();
  footer.innerHTML = await Footer.render();
  await Footer.after_render();

  content.innerHTML = await view.render();
  await view.after_render();
};

const router = new Navigo(null, true, '#');

router.on({
  '/*/reviews'        : () => { render(Review) },
  '/search'           : () => { render(Search) },
  '/*'                : () => { render(Detail) }
});

// set the default route
router.on(() => { render(Home); });

// set the 404 route
router.notFound(() => { render(Error404); });

router.resolve();
```

As an example, when I navigate to the reviews page or the search page as stated in the 'Other Routes' above, the pages do not trigger a hard reload which is what I would expect. However, once I navigate to the home / root page, it always trigger a hard refresh which I do not want.

I have a link that I use to navigate to the home / root page:

```
<a href="/">Home Page</a>
```

Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a working example ?
Also are you using hash or history mode ?
Did you tried `<a href="#/">Home Page</a>` as link ?

Comment: I am using hash mode. I have tried ```<a href="#/">Home Page</a>```, however, it creates a conflict with another route (See Detail Route above). If I try doing ```<a href="#/">Home Page</a>```, it redirects me to the detail page above.

Comment: Can you please provide a **full** working example ?

Comment: added details above